# Color ramp with legend based on attribute calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, legend, color-ramp

Using the attribute table below, I want calculate a new field using the formula `(field3+field4+field5+field6)/field7`. Field 7 will be always larger than the addition of fields 3 through 6, so the new field will be a number between 0 and 1. Lastly, each feature should be symbolized differently using a color ramp.

[image]

For example, leinster will have a dark blue color with a value of 0.7 and connacht will have a light blue color with a value of 0.3

Below is what I want the map to look like. The map needs to include a legend as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways.

1. Go to Layer Properties > Style
   [image]

and enter the expression: `ramp_color('Spectral',"col1"+"col2"/7)`

Where you should adapt the expression to fit your situation. Instead of spectral you might choose or create another color map. This won't provide you with a legend but the expression does give you more control over the coloring.

2. Create a new (virtual) column in the attribute table and fill it with the outcome of your expression.
   [image]

Again the image is just an indication of how it works, adapt it to fit your specific use. Then go to Layer Properties > Style and select 'Categorized' or 'Graduated' with 'column' set to the column with your outcome and press 'Classify'. You will now have a color and legend entry for each value. You can select the right color map here as well.